# Select a table record and view details

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a following view in my gsp page. [image]

Here I want to click or select one record in table and then click on 'SELECT' button. So that it will go to next page and show details. But I don't understand how to do it? Doesanyone has idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX methods in GRAILS something like this: 
http://grails.org/AJAX-Driven+SELECTs+in+GSP

Also, this looks more of a Javascript question. So, tagging Javascript should help.

Comment: Actually I added javascript tag but someone edited my question and removed it. I don't understand why ?